# Combining multiple SPF records, how to decide what qualifier should be used?

Tags: dns, spam-prevention, spf

I'm not sure what qualifier I should be using when trying to combine SPF records.

I know there are plenty of other questions on StackOverflow in regards to what combined SPF record is correct but there isn't one that I can find that explains clearly why a certain qualifier should be used when there are different qualifiers suggested by various services.

My current record looks like:

`v=spf1 +a +mx +ip4:111.222.333.444 include:_spf.google.com ~all include:servers.mcsv.net ?all include:mailgun.org ~all`

[Google's SPF](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33786) record is:

- `include:_spf.google.com ~all`

[Mailchimp's SPF](https://mailchimp.com/help/set-up-custom-domain-authentication-dkim-and-spf/) record is:

- `include:servers.mcsv.net ?all`

[Mailgun's SPF](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/quickstart-sending.html#how-to-verify-your-domain) record is:

- `include:mailgun.org ~all`

**How am I supposed to decide what qualifier to use** out of `+all`, `-all`, `~all` and `?all`?

What one out of the following is correct?

1. `v=spf1 +a +mx +ip4:111.222.333.444 include:_spf.google.com include:servers.mcsv.net include:mailgun.org ~all`
2. `v=spf1 +a +mx +ip4:111.222.333.444 include:_spf.google.com include:servers.mcsv.net include:mailgun.org ?all`
3. `v=spf1 +a +mx +ip4:111.222.333.444 include:_spf.google.com include:servers.mcsv.net include:mailgun.org +all`
4. `v=spf1 +a +mx +ip4:111.222.333.444 include:_spf.google.com include:servers.mcsv.net include:mailgun.org -all`

## MX & A

The same question goes to the use of `+a` and `+mx` do I need to include those too?

## What about +'s?

Do I need to include the + before `+a`, `+mx` and `+ip4`

Bare in mind we send emails through Mailchimp, MailGun, Google & via the server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your current record doesn't make sense. Rules are evaluated left to right, so your default (`all`) mechanism should always be last.

When you `include` an external SPF record, any `all` action it contains is effectively ignored (because it gets overridden by your own later directives).

MailChimp's record is dumb (*quelle surprise*); `?all` is equivalent to not having an SPF record at all, but it makes no difference in this case.

Literal IP mechanisms are fastest because they require no DNS lookups to check, so it's considered polite to put them first.

You don't need `+` in front of mechanisms as that's the default qualifier.

The `a` mechanism means "allow the IP returned by the `A` record for this host". Similarly, `mx` means "allow sending from any IP that is also a mail exchanger (mail server) for this domain". If those are true, add them. I recommend putting these before any `include` mechanisms because they only require a single DNS lookup, and they're quite likely to be already cached by receivers anyway.

You should never use `+all`; it's actively bad as it gives all sources a positive `pass` result, which is worse than having no SPF record. `?all` is the same as not having an SPF so you shouldn't use that either.

If you're also using DMARC, you should use `~all`; if you're not, use `-all`. The reason for that is that SPF rules are evaluated before DMARC, and `-all` will cause immediate termination before DMARC gets a chance to do its thing. DMARC can then be configured to reject anything that gets a `softfail`, and its reporting mechanisms can do what they are meant to do.

I'd recommend this record if you're using DMARC, and the same but `-all` if you're not:

```
v=spf1 ip4:111.222.333.444 a mx include:_spf.google.com include:servers.mcsv.net include:mailgun.org ~all
```

Whatever you end up with, check it on [Scott Kitterman's validator](https://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html?).

Comment: Thanks for your very detailed reply! To clarify there is no harm in keeping the `+` in front of mechanisms? I eventually settled with `~all` before I got to read your reply however I do not have DMARC setup; we do however have DKIM. Is there any harm in keeping `~all` rather than `-all`? Why would most sources GSuite, Mandrill, Mailgun, Outlook and many others all suggest `~all`

Comment: Yes, `+` is entirely harmless. Most places should recommend `~all` exactly because of DMARC, but they may also do it because they don’t believe you’re sufficiently committed and competent to do `-all` and don’t want the liability for breaking your email! If you have all your sources truly nailed down and you don’t use DMARC, by all means use `-all`. That said, I would recommend using DMARC anyway, if only for the insight it gives through its reporting.

Comment: Thank you very much, lots of useful information that hopefully others can benefit from.